# Google app script web app getActiveUser.getEmail() not working when deployed as USER_DEPLOYING

Tags: google-apps-script, google-authentication

I am trying to create a web app which will be using google sheets as backend. I want to enable users to access the web app and perform read/write operations through web app only. I do not want those users to have an access to the google sheet as I want to limit the data they can read through the web app. I tried using `USER_DEPLOYING` as the execute as, but doing so I am not able to get the person's email who is using the web app. Is there any way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: You should be able to access that. Could you please give more details on `I am not able to get the person's email who is using the web app`? What are you getting instead? Any error?

Comment: No, I am not getting any value there. Stackdriver logs show it as blank.

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue:

For security reasons, if a web app is deployed to `USER_DEPLOYING` (that is, `Execute the app as: Me`) and the user accessing the web app (that is, the [active user](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser())) doesn't belong to the same G Suite domain as the user under whose authority the script runs (that is, the [effective user](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#geteffectiveuser)), the script does not have access to the active user's email.

The same will happen in any context in which the script runs without user's authorization (simple triggers, etc.).

#### Explanation:

From the documentation on [getActiveUser()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser()):

> Gets information about the current user. **If security policies do not allow access to the user's identity, [User.getEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user#getEmail()) returns a blank string**. The circumstances in which the email address is available vary: for example, the user's email address is not available in any context that allows a script to run without that user's authorization, like a simple onOpen(e) or onEdit(e) trigger, a custom function in Google Sheets, or **a web app deployed to "execute as me"** (that is, authorized by the developer instead of the user). However, **these restrictions generally do not apply if the developer runs the script themselves or belongs to the same G Suite domain as the user**.

Comment: @kxm There is no workaround for retrieving the user's email when, for security reasons, you should not have access to it. That said, depending on your specific situation, maybe a workaround could be found. I'd suggest you to post a new question explaining your situation if you think that could be the case.

Comment: Thanks @Iamblichus.  I just wrote my own login solution instead.  It's not a high security application, I just need the user's email address to send them an email confirmation of their activity in the application.  Thanks for the update, though :)